# Telerik WPF RadSpreadsheet Format Cell Number Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am trying very hard to format a cell number, but it is not working as expected.

In my country we use the numbers like this: 1.000,00. The 'comma' to represent the decimal and the 'dot' to represent 'thousand' point.

What I want:  The number value to look like this: "0,824".

What I get: the number value looking like this: "823.723.228.995.058,00". (PS: I get this value from a database).

That's really weird.

I am setting the format like this:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, column].SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("#.##0,000"));
```

@Edit

Here's how exactly I am doing:

```
worksheet.Cells[0, 0].SetValue("=100*A2/A3");
        worksheet.Cells[0, 0].SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("#.##0,000"));

        worksheet.Cells[1, 0].SetValue(1000);
        worksheet.Cells[1, 0].SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("#.##0,00"));

        worksheet.Cells[2, 0].SetValue(121400.00);
        worksheet.Cells[2, 0].SetFormat(new CellValueFormat("#.##0,00"));
```

Doing like this, that weird number appears, when I Set the cell value to 0.824, like this: `worksheet.Cells[0, 0].SetValue(0.824);`, it seems to work just fine.

I have already tried a lot of formats, but none of them seems to work as I expect. I aways get the same result.

I also tried to create a NumberCellValue and I did the same thing, but again, nothing changed.

Is there any other CellValueFormat that I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: [Custom number format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not chage what character to use for decimal\group separator, only where to place it. You'll have to play with culture to change it.

Comment: I have already tried, but I realized that this problems happens when the CellvalueType is Formula. When is Number or even Text types, the format works.